# Getting spring-batch to work with transactional DMLC?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-batch

I am trying to setup jms message listener so that it picks up a certain amount of messages from a JMS broker (ActiveMQ) within the same transaction and should any error occur, the transaction is rolled back so that all message contained within that transaction end up in DLQ, or better yet, do not leave the broker.

There seems to be an implementation for a `BatchMessageListenerContainer` using spring-batch under the spring-batch-infrastucture-tests repo (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-infrastructure-tests) however that implementation involves a DB write of sorts and uses a JDBC Datasource transaction manager. In my case I am using a `JmsTransactionManager` instead.

Everything seems to be working as intended except for one thing, it seems that the listener commits the ActiveMQ transaction upon every message meaning that once the transaction rolls back, it is too late as all messages have already been collected and acknowledge back to the broker and are therefore lost.

Am I missing something? I am guessing here that I somehow need to do an extra step to intercept acknowledgement to the broker and acknowledge the bunch once the transaction is commit though I am a bit uncertain on how to go about it.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

Trace logs can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ZurJtSce

7 messages are sent through a JmsTemplate connected to the same CachingConnectionFactory (Which has the JmsTransaction connected to it) and then a `BatchMessageListenerContainer` is started to pick them up with the listener being coded to throw an exception on the 5th message.
Notice the ActiveMQSession commit messages when receiving each message starting at line 58.

Comment: Try to add code on how the transaction manager is configured, how the transaction is delimited

Comment: Hi Christian, could you elaborate? The transaction handling seems to be working. Debug messages show that every time the onmessage method is run it joins an existing transaction and that happens until my repeatPolicy says that the whole thing is complete at which point it commits the transaction. However trace messaging show a commit being done on every message from ActiveMQSession class

Comment: Have you confirmed that the behavior is actually matching the trace messages?  Also, who is providing the trace messages (can you post the logs)?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the ActiveMQ Queue before and after the error, the messages should be on ActiveMQ DLQ however only my queue exists with the amount of messages it started with minus the amount of messages which were collected in the transaction. Here's the log http://pastebin.com/ZurJtSce

Notice that I send 7 messages, then start a BMLC to pick them up. My OnMessage implementation will throw a JmsException on the 5th message and the ActiveMQ commits can be seen at each retrieval, lines 60 and forward.

Comment: Further inspection shows that if I do not use a cachingConnectionFactory and point both my BMLC and my JmsTransaction manager to an ActiveMQConnectionFactory (Also ignore TxAwareConnectionFactory), the commit is skipped however subsequent calls to consumer.receive() return null until the whole transaction is committed.
I am just lost on why this happens or how to get the JMS transaction to "sync" with the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Issue resolved.

Turns out that setting cacheLevel any higher than CACHE_CONNECTION will cause commits on every message. Lowering the level seems to have fixed the problem and session commits now only happen on transaction level whenever the policy says it is done.

Thanks for the help.